# VB.Net from table(time data type) to label

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, fetch

I have a problem regarding producing report but before that I need to run a code in order for me to create multiple conditions for the next report.

I have here a screenshot of my tbldtr. What I want is the value of am_time_in which has the data type of time will be transferred into a label/textbox/variable. I am using Visual Basic with MySQL.

Here is my code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    checktime()
End Sub

Private Sub checktime()
    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(CnPath)
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT `tbldtr`.`am_time_in` FROM `tbldtr` WHERE `tbldtr`.`id` =  '11' AND `tbldtr`.`dtrdate` =  '2017-10-16'"
    Dim daCmd5 As New MySqlCommand(Sql, cn)

    cn.Open()

    Dim datinfo As MySqlDataReader = daCmd5.ExecuteReader()

    While datinfo.Read()

        If IsDBNull(datinfo(0)) = True Then
            lblamtimein.Text = ""
        Else
            lblamtimein.Text = datinfo(0)
        End If
    End While
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Error here:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring on this line -

```
 lblamtimein.Text = datinfo(0)
```

A timespan needs to be explicitly converted to a string like this -

```
 lblamtimein.Text = datinfo(0).ToString
```